# Scrollbar is not hidden on div re sizing.

Tags: html, css

[JSFiddle for the problem.](http://jsfiddle.net/eTTZj/2489/)

I have a div inside a div. The inner div contains a check box. When the check box is checked the dimensions of the inner div exceed that of the outer div and hence we get scroll bars as the overflow property of the parentDiv is set to auto.
But when the check box is  unchecked again the scroll bars remain but the dimensions of the inner div are less than of the parent div.
It seems that the recalculation is done keeping in mind the dimensions taken up by the scroll bar. Is there a way to counter this as I don't want the scroll bars when the inner div can fit inside the outer div.

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl" class="parentDiv">
    <div class="childDiv" ng-class="{'changeSize': item.checked}">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.checked"> 
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.parentDiv {
    height : 100px;
    width : 200px;
    overflow:auto;
    border : 1px solid;
}

.childDiv {
    height : 95px;
    width : 190px;  
    border : 1px solid green;
}
.changeSize { 
    height : 150px;
    width : 250px; 
}
```

Comment: We have the integrated jsfiddle here, so may be it is better to have runnable snippets here than fiddle link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be solved by three ways.

1. You can change your overflow property to overlay (this will make your scorllbar to come on top of child div (not very nice)).

   ```
    .parentDiv {
       height : 100px;
       width : 200px;
       overflow:overlay;
       border : 1px solid;
   }
   ```
2. You can edit your parent div style to hidden and change back to auto by introducing time out.Here is the link to js fiddle 
   [JsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/126kw0zf/2/)
3. You can check if your div actually requires scrollbar or not and by that changing your css from js.
   [JsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/eTTZj/2525/)

Comment: The first approach doesn't solve my problem but the rest do.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is once the scrollbar appeared the `childDiv`'s width and height are still overflowing / touching the scrollbars. Because of this the scrollbar tends to stay even when it is unchecked.

To overcome this problem you can reduce the width and height of `childDiv` a bit more...

Like,

```
.childDiv {
    height: 80px;
    width: 175px;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```

This will make sure there is a gap between the scrollbars and the `childDiv` which will result in scrollbars disappearing once the checkbox is unchecked.

**Update:**

Add `ng-class="{'changeOverflow': item.checked}"` to your `parentDiv` like this,

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl" class="parentDiv" ng-class="{'changeOverflow': item.checked}">
    <div class="childDiv" ng-class="{'changeSize': item.checked}">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.checked"> 
   </div>
</div>
```

Change you `.parentDiv` like

```
.parentDiv {
    height : 100px;
    width : 200px;
    overflow:none;
    border : 1px solid;
}
```

Add another CSS class called `.changeOverflow` as

```
.changeOverflow {overflow:scroll;}
```

This will work :)

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Lkrjyrsa/)**

Comment: I cant reduce the dimensions of my inner div. Can there be any other solution besides altering the dimensions.

Comment: @cornercoder How about changing the width and height of outer div?